# How to send my SAML 2.0 response to verify the communication to the Service Provider?

Tags: java, saml, opensaml, service-provider, idp

**Use Case** :
*In my use case I have to do IdP-initiated SSO so I don't need an authentication request. I just need to create a SAML response in my IdP Java App to send to an already configured Service Provider to accept POST Request.*

Assuming I have a Java application using OpenSaml (**IdP**) that has created a saml response that contains a signed assertion. I also have a service provider configured to receive my saml response.

**How can I send my saml response to the service provider to verify that my response is written correctly and thus verify that the communication between the IdP and the SP is ok?**

I would like to do it in Java via a POST, but I don't know if it is possible without using a browser. The idea is just to check that the SAML response is written correctly and display the response of the POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly test your SAML configuration using a POST from Java, but you can also use a tool like Postman or cUrl.

The POST looks like this:

```
POST /SAML2/SSO/POST HTTP/1.1 
Host: sp.example.com 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Content-Length: nnn 
SAMLResponse=response&RelayState=token
```

Make sure that the `SAMLResponse` and the `RelayState` (if any) are url-encoded.

You may also want to look here: http://saml.xml.org/wiki/idp-initiated-single-sign-on-post-binding

Comment: I used Insomnia to send my post request and I was able to check the different interractions. Another way I used is to copy and paste my assertion in a simple POST form and send it manually from a browser with a SAML extension available on Chrome or Firefox to better analyze the SAML exchanges.